# Plot hole: Why couldn't Rukia and co. visit Ichigo with a gigai?

Tags: bleach

After the Hueco Mundo arc:

> Ichigo has used up all of his shinigami powers to defeat Aizen so he will no longer be able to see spirits, including his shinigami friends.

.

> They share a heartfelt goodbye thinking that they will never see each other again.

.

> [image]

But couldn't the shinigami come visit in gigai easily? I'm pretty sure Rukia had a thing for Ichigo, so it's kind of weird that she wouldn't come visit at all during the 18 months before Ichigo

> gets his powers back (duh).

Comment: That bothered me too. Rukia could also visit Ichigo's friends and set up a seance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is Rukia? A shinigami. Renji? A shinigami. I'll exclude the other Shinigami stince they are not that close with Ichigo.

Now, what is Ichigo? He was a Shinigami (Substitute), but after losing his power he is **just a normal human**.

Does normal human communicate with Shinigami? No, they are **not supposed to**. Since Ichigo is a normal human after losing his power, he and Rukia are not supposed to communicate with one another. Sure they can communicate if Rukia wears a gigai, but being a Shinigami and a Kuchiki, Rukia chose not to. Renji is a Vice-Captain, so him using a gigai to visit Ichigo every now and then would set a bad example for other Shinigami. This is the first reason, Shinigami and human are not supposed to be communicating with one another.

Another reason is that a that time, the great crisis Aizen "God" Sousuke was overcame mainly due to Ichigo's contribution. He was the one who weakened Aizen enough for the sealing kido created by Urahara to work. He has contributed more than enough in this battle. So, as a veteran, now that he lost his power and considering that he was only 17 at that time, it is perfectly understandable that the Shinigami would want Ichigo to **finally have a peaceful life** befitting of a human.

With those two reasons, it is perfectly understandable that Rukia and Ichigo parted ways there.

Also, do not forget that normally those assigned to the human world are non-seated Shinigami. Renji is a seated officer. Rukia was not but she got promoted soon after. For seated officers to visit the human world, they would need to pass a certain gate where they would have a seal applied to them which would restrict their power. This procedure requires them to fill a paperwork beforehand. If they were to use this for personal reason (visiting a friend), people would have a bad impression of them, thinking that they are using their position for their own personal needs (nepotism).

Comment: as well, they are still Gotei 13 members, and eventually both are vice capitans, so they have duties to attend to. Its not impossible that Aizen left a lot of stuff that needed to be done, and we know how much paperwork a captain and vice captain need to do normally.

Comment: Damn, that's some Montague and Capulet level separation. IchiRuka forever

Comment: The man is more shinigami than anyone, most shinigamis would want a handshake with the ultimate war hero. Explains why none is bothering him, but depriving the world savior of his dearest friends to give no "bad impression" gives a bad impression really.

Comment: @Leonid It's not like they separate forever. When Ichigo finally dies, he'd be able to rejoin his shinigami friends. Therefore, while he is still a living human being, the least the Shinigami can do for the guy is to give him a peaceful human life.

Answer (score 0):

After the Thousand Year War she visits Ichigo from time to time with Renji, and bless the great mind of Urahara, because he invented the Soul Society, a world of living "Discord", so now they can talk more often.

Comment: I'm confused reading this answer. I may believe the first part about the Thousand-Year War (though source/reference is needed)... but Discord and Civ 6?

Comment: @AkiTanaka If I understand correctly, this user is comparing the Soul Society to Discord, and jokingly suggesting that Ichigo and Rukia could play Civ 6 together while inside it. I've tidied up the answer a bit to make it clearer and remove the jokey part.